# Allow multi-selection for a field based on an external content type?

Tags: external-content-type, lookup-column

The choice field and lookup field allow for multiple selections. I can't find that option for lookups to external content types. Is it possible to do this?

(I want to assign documents to one or more clients, using a clients list coming from CRM 2011 using ECTs.)

Comment: I haven't been able to test, but at least [one other person](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/25b319e6-d212-4f3e-ac44-a23820bc0a59) hasn't found it possible. Does trying MS' suggestion in that thread work?

Comment: Nope, once you select an External List as source for your Lookup the 'allow multiple selections' checkbox is grayed-out/hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup column based on an external list, but you can't have multiple selections or bring in additional columns. This is a limitation of the external list data in SharePoint 2010.

See [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/6eae6ab4-cb79-418d-b831-eb23fe32c29e).